# Jdatabase : Sorting two selections?

Tags: mysql, jdatabase

I have `Jdatabase table` having attendance data of all my students.

***EXAMPLE :***

[image: table]

I need to display the attendance of all roll numbers for class 3. The records having 3 in `attended_no` column were present and records not having 3 in the `attended_no` column were absent.

This should be the output :

`ABC-12-21` `Present`

`ABC-12-24` `Present`

`ABC-12-29` `Absent`

`ABC-12-37` `Absent`

`ABC-12-42` `Present`

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you need to use 2 queries. try the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('roll_no', 'attended_no'))
      ->from($db->qn('#__attendance'))
      ->order('roll_no ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($results as $row)
{
    $array = explode(',', $row->attendance_no); // convert commas to array
    $flag  = in_array(3, $array);               //check if '3' in in the array

    if ($flag == null)
    {
        $flag='absent';
    }
    else
    {
        $flag='present';
    }

    echo '<li>' . $row->roll_no . ' : ' . $flag . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I had posted an example above. The actual table structure is more complex. I cannot select all the roll number at once. I can only select the present and absent records one by one. Now I need to join and sort them alphabetically.

Comment: I'm not sure how the table structure should be preventing you from selecting all roll numbers at once based on the `$subject`.

Comment: I updated my question. Check the edit, may be you can now get the idea of what the actual question was.

Comment: @Saibbyweb - I've updated the query in my answer. Please test again

Comment: Thanks, but can you edit it a bit in context of the table in the question (which has no flag column).

Comment: I'm confused now, both your queries in your question are referencing the `#__attendance` table...

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I removed the queries from the question and made it more simpler to understand now. Have a look now and answer in context to that table.

Comment: @Saibbyweb - updated again. let me know if it works

Comment: I updated and got it to work somehow. Thanks for the idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

In a similar way, you have to compose a query to return the results that your require. Something like:

```
SELECT P.roll_num+A.roll_num FROM PRESENT P, ABSENT A 
WHERE 
P.subject_co = A.subject_co AND P.flag = 1 AND A.flag = 0
ORDER BY P.subject_co
```

In case, you are looking to return a UNION of your previous queries, it is even simpler:

**Using the union methods in database queries**
https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_union_methods_in_database_queries

Comment: Can you explain this query please? Whats `P.` and `A.` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can spare yourself a lot of php code bloat by writing a refined sql `SELECT` clause with a conditional expression:

```
SELECT roll_num, IF(attended_no REGEXP '(^|,)3(,|$)', 'Present', 'Absent')
```

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f850a7/2)

The regular expression checks that the `3` value is never preceded or followed by another number -- so that `13` and `39` are never falsely matched.  The regex pattern will correctly match if the 3 is the first value, the last value, or the only value in the comma separated string.

What does the regular expression mean?  I'm glad you asked...

```
(    #start of capture group 1
^    #match the start position of the input string
|    #or
,    #match a comma
)    #end of capture group 1
3    #match the literal digit 3
(    #start of capture group 2
,    #match a comma
|    #or
$    #match the end position of the input string
)    #end of capture group 2
```

When you want to understand what a pattern is doing or you wish to test some fringe scenarios, [feed it to regex101.com and upskill yourself](https://regex101.com/r/ENTA36/1).